# a* (astar) Pathfinding issue: I Can’t reference variables from other scripts in order to determine aipath target

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, path-finding, a-star

I’m trying to have my enemies’ ai target my player until the point where an enemy hits him and he dies. After that, I want the enemies to disperse and then target and move to a random spawn point (simply because they are all around the edge of the screen).

Here’s what I have in the update method of the AIDestinationSetter script:

```
void Update () {

if (GameObject.FindWithTag("Player").GetComponent<PlayerMovement>().canMove)

{

target = GameObject.FindWithTag("Player").transform;

}

else

{

//randomise movement of all enemies - to spawnpoints at this stage

Transform[] spawnPoints = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("WaveSpawner").GetComponent<WaveSpawner>().spawnPoints; //find spawnpoints

//create array of enemies

GameObject[] enemies = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("Enemy");

foreach (GameObject enemy in enemies) //for each enemy in the array

{

enemy.GetComponent<AIDestinationSetter>().target = spawnPoints[Random.Range(0, spawnPoints.Length)];//set aipath destination to a random spawnpoint

Debug.Log(enemy.GetComponent<AIDestinationSetter>().target);

}

}

if (target != null && ai != null) ai.destination = target.position;

}
```

(canMove is simply a boolean that is set to true at the start of the game and false when an enemy hits the player. It lives within a script called PlayerMovement that is a component of my GambeObject player.)

(spawnPoints is an array of spawn points that lives inside a script called Wavespawner that is a component of my GameObject Wavespawner… Not the best naming convention I know…)

The problem lies somewhere with me trying to reference the PlayerMovement and Wavespawner scripts in my GetComponent methods.Unity is throwing the errors:

> error CS0246: The type or namespace name ‘PlayerMovement’ could not be
> found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
>
> error CS0246: The type or namespace name ‘WaveSpawner’ could not be
> found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Any help with this matter would be really appreciated. I’ve tried to figure this out for hours now and everything I try just breaks it even more.

Answer (score 1):

## TL;DR

The proper way to setup references between objects is in [MonoBehaviour.Awake](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.Awake.html) :

> you should use Awake to set up references between scripts

Few more tips:

- make fields out of `GetComponent<T>`, don't query about them in `Update` as it's expensive
- use `Debug.Log(...)` to write to console
- use `Assert.IsNotNull`, `Assert.IsTrue` etc to check conditions
- use breakpoints in your debugger

**And about your CS0246 error:**

Go to your `PlayerMovement.cs` file:

Take note of its namespace, e.g.:

```
namespace MyCoolGame
{
    class PlayerMovement {}
}
```

Then go back to the script you have the error on and put `using MyCoolGame;` at beginning.

The error should now be fixed.

Comment: Hi, thanks so much for your reply.

Are you sure Awake is the best place to set the target? If it only called once during the lifetime of the script instance then how will it know to switch targets when the player is defeated?

Also, there is no namespace in my PlayerMovement.cs file. It starts off with: 

using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class PlayerMovement : MonoBehaviour
{

Comment: If I go into the PlayerMovement file and add a namespace (also called PlayerMovement) I get the following error: error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'PlayerMovement' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)